# Почему при конвертации листа в множество, входившего в отдельную функцию, выводится "System.String[]"?

Tags: c#

Пытался конвертировать как внутри функции, как и снаружи *(выводило System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String])*, прикрепил код, в котором конвертировал List в Array внутри функции и поменял static List на static Array в начале функции Solution. *Не понимаю почему в таком случае выводится "System.String[]"; Уже искал решение в интернете*

Условие задачи: у вас 5 печений и дано несколько зданий, в которых живут люди, найдите индексы данных зданий, сумма двух которых будет равна количеству печенья

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            int Cookies = 5; var houses = new List<int>() { 2, 4, 5, 7, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 9 };
            Console.WriteLine(Solution(houses.Count - 1, houses, Cookies));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static Array Solution(int a, List<int> b, int c)
        {
            var Answer = new List<String>() { };
            int Curr = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++)
            {
                
                while (i < a) {
                    while (Curr <= a)
                    {
                        if (Curr == i) { Curr++; }
                        if ((b[i] + b[Curr]) == c)
                        {
                            Answer.Add(Convert.ToString(i) + ";" + Convert.ToString(Curr-1)); Curr++;
                        }
                        else { Curr++; Console.WriteLine(Curr);}
                    }
                    i++;Curr = 0;
                }
            }
            return Answer.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", Solution(houses.Count - 1, houses, Cookies)));`